# Workflow on how to git commit to new branch that is based on other branch

Tags: git

My scenario:

- I'm working on a branch
- have a few commits on that local branch
- have changes in my working folder

Now I discover a small bug or typo.

- I want to commit to a (new) branch
- that new branch should not be based on the current branch but on for example 'master'
- that new branch should not be checked out, I want to stay in the current branch and continue

My current workflow is using tortoise git, commit to a new branch, then rebase that branch by remove all commits except the last and then checkout my 'current' branch again.

Current flow

```
git branch my-typo-fix master
git checkout my-typo-fox
git add myfile
git commit -m "Typo in my file"
git checkout my-current-branch
```

That doesn't always work when the pending changes conflict and that is also not what I want to commit onto that fix branch. Also this isn't really efficient.

Can this workflow be improved or maybe I'm doing it completely wrong?

### Update

Slightly improved workflow based on comment by Mykhailo

```
git checkout -b my-typo-fix master
git add myfile
git commit -m "Typo in my file"
git checkout my-current-branch
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can this workflow be improved

`git stash` is made for this:

```
git stash
git checkout master
git checkout -b my-typo-fix
# make change
git add ...
git commit ...
git checkout my-current-branch
git stash pop
```

> that new branch should not be checked out, I want to stay in the current branch

Then you have to clone the repository into another working directory and make your fix there. `git commit` per definition always work on the branch currently checked out. But the end result of the given approach is the same.

Comment: Using stash will result in the change that I made to be gone from the working folder, correct?

Comment: Yes, and they will be back when you pop.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you could combine

```
git branch my-typo-fix master
git checkout my-typo-fix
```

with

```
git checkout -b my-typo-fix master
```

According to [Git docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout),

> Specifying -b causes a new branch to be created as if git-branch
>   were called and then checked out.

Additionally you could use `git stash` ([Git docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash)) in order to temporarily stash your changes from working copy (before switching to fix branch) and reapply those changes with `git stash pop` after switching branch back. This will help to avoid conflicts during checkout.

Comment: I didn't know you can add the source branch to `git checkout`